# Reverse for 'onePart' with keyword arguments - issue

Tags: python, django

I've try to make my url like *description/(party_number)-(pk)*, where *party_number* and *pk* are different for each object. But istead of this I get error:

> Reverse for 'onePart' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 10, 'nums':'A15151'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:['description/(?:(?P[\d]+)-(?P[\d]+)/)?$']

in my **views.py:**

```
def PartyNumView(request, page_number = 1):
    all_parties = Part.objects.all()
    current_page = Paginator(all_parties, 2)
    try:
        context = current_page.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        context = current_page.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        context = current_page.page(current_page.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('part_list.html', {'PartyNum': context})


def forOne(request, pk):
    onePart = get_object_or_404(Part, pk=pk)
    return render_to_response('singlePart.html', {'onePart': onePart})
```

my **urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^parties/(?P<page_number>[\d]+)/$', PartyNumView),
    url(r'^parties', PartyNumView),
    url(r'description/(?:(?P<nums>[\d]+)-(?P<pk>[\d]+)/)?$', forOne, name='onePart'),
    url(r'^main/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main.html')),       #static html
    url(r'^measures/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='IcDesc.html')),       #static html

]
```

And **part_list.html:**

```
{% for object in PartyNum %}

    <tr>
      <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'onePart' pk=object.pk nums=object.Party_number %}"> {{ object.Party_number }}</a></td>
      <td>{{ object.Film }}</td>
      <td>{{ object.Thick }}</td>
      <td>{{ object.Critical_temperature }}</td>
      <td>{{ object.R_s }}</td>

  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `A15151` is not string that compiles under following regex `[\d]+)` -> ( just digits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the position of your URL arguments, put `Party_number` as the first argument in your template.

```
<td><a href="{% url 'onePart' nums=object.Party_number pk=object.pk %}">...</td>
```

As I clearly see in the traceback arguments `{'pk': 10, 'nums':'A15151'}` `Party_number` may contain not only digits, so your regex expression is wrong.

Instead of this

```
 url(r'description/(?:(?P<nums>[\d]+)-(?P<pk>[\d]+)/)?$', forOne, name='onePart'),
```

try:

```
url(r'description/(?P<nums>\w.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', forOne, name='onePart'),
```

That urls calls the view  `def forOne(request, pk):` which doesn't have the required argument `nums`. better to have the argument with a default value

```
def forOne(request, pk, nums=None):
    ''' '''
```